# Attempt to read property “client_name” on null

Tags: php, laravel-8

Context: I am not familiar with PHP and was left to spin up an environment since the previous dev left.

I am getting the error in my `resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php`

```
 <div class="user-wrapper">
            <img class="user-img" src="{{ asset('images/user-circle.svg')}}" alt="User"/>
            <div class="user-info">
              <h3>{{ Auth::user()->name}}</h3>
              <p> {{ Auth::user()->email}}</p>
              <p> {{ Auth::user()->client->client_name}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is my Client model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
      'client_name',
      'description',
    ];
}
```

And the User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'client_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    
    public function client(){
      return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');
    }
}
```

I can get the name and email from my database just fine but for the client it somehow returns null. I have also verified that I can get the data from the client tables.

EDIT:
I added the following lines in Client Model as suggested but I still get the

```
 public function client(){
      return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan migrate
```